# WPF - pass data from page A to page B

Tags: wpf

So I want to pass data when I clicked an `Canvas`. So I have this code;

```
Canvas event_canvas = new Canvas();
                        event_canvas.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(66, 70, 77));
                        event_canvas.Width = 250;
                        event_canvas.Height = 60;
                        event_canvas.Margin = new Thickness(40, 0, 0, 0);
                        event_canvas.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
                        event_canvas.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
                        event_canvas.Cursor = Cursors.Hand;
                        #endregion

                        #region Grid (event_grid)
                        Grid event_grid = new Grid();
                        event_grid.Width = 250;
                        event_grid.Height = 60;
                        #endregion

                        #region TextBlock (event_text)
                        TextBlock event_text = new TextBlock();
                        event_text.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
                        event_text.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
                        event_text.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(255, 255, 255));
                        event_text.Text = e.name;
                        #endregion

                        event_grid.Children.Add(event_text); // Add the textblock to the grid
                        event_canvas.Children.Add(event_grid);  // Add the grid to the canvas                    
                        grid_events.Children.Add(event_canvas);    // Add the canvas to the main grid.

                        // Click event registration
                        event_canvas.MouseLeftButtonDown += Event_canvas_MouseLeftButtonDown;
```

And then in the trigger;

```
private void Event_canvas_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
            {
                Page pg = new EventDetailPage();
                // Replaces all the content!!!!!
                this.Content = pg;
                //throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
```

I tried to add this;

```
var param = ((TextBlock)sender).Text;
Page pg = new EventDetailPage(param);
```

But that code doesn't work, it throws an error that I can't get a value.
How can I fix this issue?

Comment: I don't see what this has got to do with passing events between pages. Either attach your handler to the textblock or use e.originalsource rather than sender

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cast the `sender` argument to `Canvas` and then access the `Grid` through the `Canvas`' `Children` collecton and the `TextBlock` through the `Grid`'s `Children` collecton:

```
private void Event_canvas_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    Canvas canvas = (Canvas)sender;
    Grid event_grid = canvas.Children[0] as Grid;
    TextBlock event_text = event_grid.Children[0] as TextBlock;
    string text = event_text.Text;
    ...
}
```